# Converting from Private Key to WIF, what am i missing?

Tags: wallet, private-key, wallet-import-format

They say a image speaks louder then 1000 words so:

[image]

As you can see from the image above, this should work ?
What am i missing here?

This is my encode function,
http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/currency/coinstring/

I can confirm the private key spitted out is in correct format for if i do a dump i get:

```
$ ./src/d-cli dumpprivkey WRSybD94sWugjAQ89zyvbLsnw76ovCYEGo
BxkN86fdFBN75Aat3WCDs9w6NRHCMJJvvrDgb44Vcc23f96ohFZ5
```

Comment: How does your `encode()` function work? You probably aren't encoding it as base58 correctly or you are encoding the wrong thing (e.g. hex string instead of the bytes themselves).

Comment: sorry i edited my question to tell about my encode function, http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/currency/coinstring/ and i can confirm the spitted out key is in correct format, the PREFIX is 100% correct as you can see by the image and code reference, really struggling with this one :(

Comment: You can see on the referenced encode() function that im sure im doing everything correct?

Comment: the issue was in the encode() function thanks kindly

Answer (score 1):

The issue as suggest by Andrew was in the encode function.
After using https://www.npmjs.com/package/wif everything worked perfectly as intended.

Comment: and here is the list of address prefixes: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes